# Remove rows if a specific column has values (strings) that match a vector of substrings

Tags: r

The `redundant.gs` vector contains substrings that might match with the `gs_name` column in the `all.gene.sets` dataframe. I want to remove all such matches.
My code below only removes rows that match the first substring `ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED` but not the second or subsequent substrings.

```
redundant.gs <- c("ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED", "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN")
gene.sets <- all.gene.sets[!(all.gene.sets$gs_name %like% redundant.gs),]
```

Data:

```
all.gene.sets <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gs_cat, ~gs_subcat,    ~gs_name,
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_DN",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_DN",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_DN",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_DN",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_DN",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "ANDERSON_BLOOD_CN54GP140_ADJUVANTED_WITH_GLA_AF_AGE_18_45YO_1DY_UP",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN_CAUCASIAN_MALE_AGE_18_40YO_HIGH_RESPONDERS_1DY_3DY_POSITIVE_PREDICTIVE_OF_TITER",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN_CAUCASIAN_MALE_AGE_18_40YO_HIGH_RESPONDERS_1DY_3DY_POSITIVE_PREDICTIVE_OF_TITER",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN_CAUCASIAN_MALE_AGE_18_40YO_HIGH_RESPONDERS_1DY_3DY_POSITIVE_PREDICTIVE_OF_TITER",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN_CAUCASIAN_MALE_AGE_18_40YO_HIGH_RESPONDERS_1DY_3DY_POSITIVE_PREDICTIVE_OF_TITER",
  "C7",    "VAX",         "BUCASAS_PBMC_FLUARIX_FLUVIRIN_CAUCASIAN_MALE_AGE_18_40YO_HIGH_RESPONDERS_1DY_3DY_POSITIVE_PREDICTIVE_OF_TITER",
  "C7",    "IMMUNESIGDB", "GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN",
  "C7",    "IMMUNESIGDB", "GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN",
  "C7",    "IMMUNESIGDB", "GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN",
  "C7",    "IMMUNESIGDB", "GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN",
  "C7",    "IMMUNESIGDB", "GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapse `redundant.gs` into a single string separated by `"|"`, then use as a pattern in `grepl()`:

```
keep.rows <- !grepl(
  paste(redundant.gs, collapse = "|"),
  all.gene.sets$gs_name
)

all.gene.sets[keep.rows, ]
```

```
   gs_cat   gs_subcat                                            gs_name
17     C7 IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
18     C7 IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
19     C7 IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
20     C7 IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
21     C7 IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
all.gene.sets %>%
  filter(str_detect(gs_name, str_c(redundant.gs, collapse = "|"), negate = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  gs_cat gs_subcat   gs_name                                           
  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>                                             
1 C7     IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
2 C7     IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
3 C7     IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
4 C7     IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
5 C7     IMMUNESIGDB GSE21063_3H_VS_16H_ANTI_IGM_STIM_NFATC1_KOBCELL_DN
```